# Django Error Logging: AdminEmailHandler failing silently

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with the following logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': 'LEVEL:%(levelname)s TIME:%(asctime)s MODULE:%(module)s LINE:%(lineno)d PROCESS:%(process)d THREAD:%(thread)d MESSAGE:%(message)s'
    }},
    'handlers': {
        # Include the default Django email handler for errors
        # This is what you'd get without configuring logging at all.
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
             # But the emails are plain text by default - HTML is nicer
            'include_html': True,
            'filters : [],
        },
        # Log to a text file that can be rotated by logrotate
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': '/[more stuff here]/statistics/logs/django.log',
            'formatter' : 'verbose'
            'filters : [],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # Again, default Django configuration to email unhandled exceptions
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins','logfile'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        # Might as well log any errors anywhere else in Django
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile','mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

If `include_html` is set to `True` I don't receive any error e-mails and the handler doesn't even open a connection to the SMTP server (I verified this using a Python SMTP server replacement). When setting `include_html = False` everything works fine, so I suppose it is an issue with a malformatted error message or an encoding problem.

How can I retrieve the exception generated by the **AdminEMailHandler** during logging? Right now the handler just fails silently, which is really bad for a handler that logs critical errors.

Comment: In my case, when I set `include_html` to `True`, the email server will reject to send it because the email looks like spam.

Comment: This might be a problem with the e-mail settings @shellbyte. If you send e-mail from your server with a "from" header that's from another domain, make sure to update the DNS settings for that domain.